# Си: Конвертация uint8_t в char

Tags: c

Есть некий массив uint8_t. Например

```
uint8_t myu[4] = {0xff, 0x068, 0xc5, 0x8f};
```

Этот массив нужно конвертировать в строку, чтобы получилось **ff68c58f**. Не понимаю как...
*printf("%02x", myu[i])* для каждого элемента массива выводит на экран нужный результат... Но нужно это не вывести на экран, а передать в переменную

Comment: Идея utf8 - это совместимость unicode с сишным char, когда unicode строка разбита на последовательность char, т.е. массив utf8 - это массив из char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все очень просто:

```
  uint8_t myu[4] = {0xff, 0x068, 0xc5, 0x8f};
  int i, sz = sizeof(myu) / sizeof(myu[0]);
  char res[2 * sz + 1];

  for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    sprintf(res + 2 * i, "%02x", myu[i]);
```

Если что-то непонятно -- спрашивайте.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", myu[0], myu[1], myu[2], myu[3]);
```

Или

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    printf("%02X", myu[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357065/1159507

Comment: вывести в строку, а не на экран

Comment: @hardsky Хмм, странно, вопрос вроде был изменен, но не вижу в нем правок. Или может я действительно невнимательно читал, но в любом случае по ссылке есть вариант со строкой.

Answer (score 0):

В лоб: заводите временный массив tmp[8], каждый байт из myu через sprintf пишете в него, потом strcat(result, tmp).
Чуть элегантнее: делаете функцию, которая преобразует байт в 2 соответствующих hex-символа и последовательно применяете ее на myu, записывая результат куда надо.

Comment: utf8 мапится в char 1 в 1

Comment: Если из {0xff, 0x068, 0xc5, 0x8f} нужно получить строку "ff68c58f" это как поможет?

Comment: заводите массив char tmp[5], пишете туда 4 элемента из массива, а в 5 добавляете \0, и получаете сишную строку

Comment: Попробуйте и покажите что получится для {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}.

Comment: Ну во первых не было указано, что за строку нужно получить, если нужно смапить подмножество ascii из utf8 в сишную char* то мой ответ правильный, если речь о юникоде то ваш ответ (в общем случае) некоректный, т.к. юникодный символ - это 4 байта.

Comment: Прочитайте все же вопрос: ТС явно пишет что printf c "%02x" дает нужный результат на экране, а ему нужно получить строку с тем же содержимым. И да, перевод bin2hex работает по такой схеме для любых данных вообще.

Comment: 2 хекса - это char

Comment: ок, вы имеете ввиду, что байт 0xff нужно перевести в строку (т.к. в 2 байта содержащих 2 символа FF)

Comment: @hardsky Мне нужно не 2 hex - char, a 2 hexa -> 2 char'a. Т.е 0х00 - это не терминатор, а "00"

Comment: да @ВладимирМартьянов, все вам правильно подсказал.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ваш ответ очень похож на правду...

Comment: @elp87 он и есть правда :-) Если вам нужно "в лоб" - sprintf + strcat. Если нужно быстро - преобразование байта через битовые операции и пару if и помещение результата сразу в буфер. Там в комментариях есть еще промежуточный вариант: sprintf и изменение указателя.